# want to apply merge function on column A

Tags: python, pandas, string, merge, apply

How can I apply merge function or any other method on column A.
For example in layman term I want to convert this string "(A|B|C,D)|(A,B|C|D)|(B|C|D)" into a
"(D A|D B|D C)|(A B|A C|A D)|(B|C|D)"

This (B|C|D) will remain same as it doesn't have comma value to merge in it. Basically I want to merge the values which are in commas to rest of its other values.

I have below data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [ '(A|B|C,D)|(A,B|C|D)|(B|C|D)'],
        'B(Expected)': [ '(D A|D B|D C)|(A B|A C|A D)|(B|C|D)']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)
```

My expected result is mentioned in column B(Expected)

Below method I tried:-
(1)

```
df['B(Expected)'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("|", " ").replace(",", "|") if "|" in x and "," in x else x)
```

(2)

```
# Split the string by the pipe character
df['string'] = df['string'].str.split('|')
df['string'] = df['string'].apply(lambda x: '|'.join([' '.join(i.split(' ')) for i in x]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to extract the values in parentheses, then a custom function with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to reorganize the values:

```
from itertools import product

def split(s):
    return '|'.join([' '.join(x) for x in product(*[x.split('|') for x in s.split(',')])])

df['B'] = df['A'].str.replace(r'([^()]+)', lambda m: split(m.group()), regex=True)

print(df)
```

*Note that this requires non-nested parentheses.*

Output:

```
                             A                                    B
0  (A|B|C,D)|(A,B|C|D)|(B|C|D)  (A D|B D|C D)|(A B|A C|A D)|(B|C|D)
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/76768798/19812003 @mozway can you please help?

Comment: @Jawed, sure I provided an answer